# Confused about the for loop in the Set Covering Problem (Greedy Algorithms)

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, set, set-cover

This is my first time learning data structure and algorithms. I am stuck in the Grokking Algorithm Chapter 8 Greedy Algorithms, where there is a simple Set Covering Problem given to the readers.

Is there a simpler example of source code which I can refer to understand the concept behind this example?

Can somebody explain how set intersection helps to get the ultimate result of {'k4', 'k5'} in plain English? How is the array of states_needed passed in to a hash and gets converted to a set?

```
states_needed = set(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"])

stations = {}

stations["k1"] = set(["a", "b", "c"])
stations["k2"] = set(["c", "d", "e"])
stations["k3"] = set(["f", "g", "h"])
stations["k4"] = set(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
stations["k5"] = set(["e", "f", "g", "h"])

final_stations = set()

while states_needed:
  best_station = None
  states_not_covered = set()
  
  for station, states_for_station in stations.items():
    covered = states_needed & states_for_station
    if len(covered) > len(states_not_covered):
      best_station = station
      states_not_covered = covered

  states_needed -= states_not_covered
  final_stations.add(best_station)

print(final_stations)
```

Comment: It is a greedy algorithm, set intersection enables being the "greediest" at each step, by picking the set that covers the most (i.e. has the largest intersection) of the elements of the set that have not been covered. In the formal proof of the cost of this greedy approximation algorithm vs. the optimal (brute-force) algorithm, set intersection is used to relate the "price" paid for each element in the sets picked to the number of sets picked.

Answer (score -1):

1. **Initialize Data:**

   - `states_needed`: A set of states that need coverage.
   - `stations`: A dictionary where each key is a station name, and the corresponding value is a set of states that this station covers.
2. **Greedy Algorithm Implementation:**

   - `final_stations`: A set that will eventually contain the final selection of stations.
   - The `while` loop runs as long as there are states that still need coverage.
   - In each iteration of the loop, the code tries to find the best station that covers the maximum number of uncovered states.
3. **Finding the Best Station:**

   - `best_station`: Temporarily holds the best station found in the current iteration.
   - `states_not_covered`: A set to keep track of states covered by the `best_station`.
   - The `for` loop iterates over each station and calculates the set of uncovered states (`covered`) that this station would cover.
   - If the current station covers more states than the current best (comparing lengths of `covered` and `states_not_covered`), it becomes the new `best_station`, and `states_not_covered` is updated.
4. **Updating States and Final Stations:**

   - After finding the best station for the iteration, `states_needed` is updated to remove the states that are now covered.
   - The chosen `best_station` is added to `final_stations`.
5. **Output:**

   - Once all states are covered (i.e., `states_needed` becomes empty), the loop exits.
   - The `final_stations` set now contains the station names that collectively cover all the required states with the least number of stations (according to the greedy approach).
6. **Print Result:**

   - The code prints the `final_stations`, which is the set of stations chosen by the algorithm.